# Confusion understanding probability

Tags: probability

I am a beginner in this forum - please don't judge me too harsh.

I understand that my question is noobie but I read a lot and couldn't understand the concept of summing probabilities.

Here is the problem I cannot understand:
We have a dice with 6 possible outcomes 1...6.
Rolling the dice once, the chance to hit 3 is 1/6

What is the chance to hit 3 if I throw the dice 6 times or 8 times?

Simply summing the probabilities doesn't make sense to me.
I mean 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6  = 8/6 is greater than 1. How come probability gets greater than 1?
My reasoning must be wrong

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that each throw of a die has a $(1/6)$ chance of rolling a $(3)$.  Therefore, your addition is correct that if you roll the die $8$ times, the expected number of times that you will roll a $(3)$ is

$$8 \times (1/6) = (8/6) = (4/3) > 1.$$

Your intuition is also right, that if you roll the die $8$ times, the chance of **at least** one of the rolls coming up $(3)$ **must be less than $(1)$**.

This begs the question: if the distribution of $8$ rolls is such that you expect $(4/3)$ of the rolls to be a $3$, how can the chance of **not rolling any $(3)$** in 8 rolls, **still** be positive.

It is because there is a (small) chance, that in $8$ rolls, you may have a $3$ appear **two or more times.**  It is the possibility of a $3$ appearing **two or more times** that balances the fact that there is still a positive chance that there will be no $(3)$'s rolled.

However, this is all intuitive hand waving, which doesn't mean much, without math to back it up.

Suppose that you roll a die $8$ times.  There are $(6)$ possibilities for each roll.  Therefore, the total number of possible sequences of $8$ rolls is $6^8$.

For $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,8\}$, a natural question is: how many of the $6^8$ sequences will result in exactly $k$ of the rolls coming up $(3)$.

There are $\frac{8!}{k!(8-k)!} = \binom{8}{k}$ ways of selecting $k$ rolls out of $8$, so that those rolls (and only those rolls) come up $3$.

Once the $k$ rolls are selected, you then have $(8-k)$ rolls whose only constraint is that the roll is any number other than a $(3)$.

Therefore, there are exactly $\left[\binom{8}{k} \times 5^{(8-k)}\right]$ sequences of $8$ rolls, in which $3$ comes up exactly $k$ times.

Therefore, the probability of this happening is

$$P(k) = \frac{\binom{8}{k} \times 5^{(8-k)}}{6^8}.$$

You will find that :

- $\sum_{k = 0}^8 [k \times P(k)] = (8/6) = (4/3)$, as expected.
- $P(0) = \frac{\binom{8}{0} \times 5^{(8-0)}}{6^8} = \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^8 > 0.$

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have the probability of hitting ONLY once 3, a favoruable event is this

$$\{3,\overline{3},\overline{3},\overline{3},\overline{3},\overline{3}\}$$

where with $\overline{3}$ I mean "not 3"

This probability is $\frac{1}{6}\times\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5$ because all this events must happen together.

Now you can understand that the "3" can be hit in any of the six positions, thus this probability must be multiplied by 6

Concluding, the probability to hit exactly one 3 in 6 dice's rolls is

$$6\times\frac{1}{6}\times\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5$$

Comment: Use ```\left(``` and ```\right)``` instead of ```(``` and ```)``` wherever the size of brackets is to be adjusted. For example, $\left(\dfrac56\right)$ vs $(\dfrac56)$.

Comment: @ultralegend5385: yes, of course....I was in a hurry. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the probability that you roll $3$ *at least* once in $n$ attempts, then you can calculate it as follows.

Let $A$ be the event that you roll $3$ at least once in $n$ attempts.

Then the complement, $A^c$, is the event that you do not roll $3$ on any of the attempts. The probability of $A^c$ is $(5/6)^n$.

Therefore, the probability of $A$ is $P(A) = 1 - P(A^c) = 1 - (5/6)^n$.

For example, if $n = 6$ then $P(A) \approx 0.6651$. If $n=8$ then $P(A) \approx 0.7674$.